# ERROR: View layout not found

Tags: laravel

View [layout] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\resources\views\sportstable.blade.php). This error occur everytime I try to return a view on Laravel 5.4

Comment: Please include the blade code that is including this particular blade file and generating this error.

Answer (score 0):

It means that laravel is trying to load layout.blade view but it seams it doesn't exist in your project or the @include path to layout.blade itself is wrong.
Can you show your code?